# certbot ACMEv1 transition to ACMEv2

Tags: ssl, certbot, acme

We currently run our own installer when building a new Ubuntu 18.04 deployment. It creates an SSL cert for us using the following command:

`certbot certonly --non-interactive -d $domain -d www.$domain --agree-tos -m X@X.com --webroot --webroot-path /var/platform/X > /dev/null`

Unfortunately, all of the staff who knew this system have been let go because of COVID-19.

I think that these commands create an ACMEv1 SSL cert, and that it will no longer be possible to create ACMEv1 certs for new domains after June 1 2020.

Will the command above continue to work? I am totally out of my comfort zone here, so any help would be massively appreciated.

Please treat me like a newbie in your responses, this is not something I have any knowledge of and it's been thrown at me with 3 weeks to solve. FML.

Comment: Your question is unfortunately off topic here as not related to programming, but where does your feeling on "I think that these commands create an ACMEv1 SSL cert, and that it will no longer be possible to create ACMEv1 certs for new domains after June 1 2020." come from? If you use an up to date `certbot` client you won't have problems. See https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-upgrade-to-support-acmev2/110720/2: "recent versions of Certbot use the ACMEv2 server by default. You don’t have to configure anything."